# Allow user to enter text when completing an in app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm creating an app that has in-app purchases. Is there a way that when the user purchases an item they can send a specialized message with the purchase?
e.g. when the purchase is complete another box pops up where they can type a message and it will send to my email.

Comment: you are asking if there Is a way, yes of course, purchase events have callbacks that gets triggered when the event fires.
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever the state of a transaction changes the control goes to updatedTransactions callback. Here depending on the state,when it is purchased, you can show any popup and connect it with you email sending functionality.